# send notification when delete user

Tags: django

How can I send email notification when delete user from list?
I have a form on the site. With it, I add the user.When the user is added, I receive a notification to the mail. How can I get notified when a user is deleted?
Views.py:

```
class CreateUser(CreateView):
    template_name = 'staffweb/add_user.html'

    form_class = AddUserForm
    model = StaffPersonal
    context_object_name = 'staff'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        new_user = form.save()
        new_user_name = new_user.full_name
        msg_args = ['New user added: ' + new_user_name]
        send_to_bot('\n'.join((msg_args)))
        email_text = make_letter(*msg_args)
        send_to_email(settings.ADMIN_EMAIL, email_text)
        return super(CreateUser, self).form_valid(form)


class DetailUser(DetailView):
    template_name = 'staffweb/user.html'
    model = StaffPersonal
    context_object_name = 'user'


class DeleteUser(DeleteView):
    model = StaffPersonal
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you just copy the email sending part from CreateUser to DeleteUser and change the message text?

Comment: One way would be to override the `DeleteUser`'s `post()` method. Another way would be to override the model's `delete()` method (which would then send the email if deleted from anywhere, not only this view).

Comment: quinz, when I create a user, I get its fields when the form is saved. I do not know how to get the fields when I delete it, for example the name

Comment: Redefined the post method as advised by Petr. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using django signals.

The **post_delete signal** is sent at the end of a model’s delete() method and a queryset’s delete() method. So whenever you model gets deleted, django sends a post_delete signal. You can catch this signal and do something after deleting it. Similarly signals are sent after creation and updation as well. Signals are simple to implement.

Something like this
    in your models.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_delete, sender=StaffPersonal)
def send_email_after_delete(sender , instance , **kwargs):
    #send your mail here.
    #parameter instance is the model instance being deleted.
    #Note that instance has been deleted form the database and exists only at the application(django) level. 
    #As the docs suggest, one should be careful while using it.
    return
```

The function **send_email_after_delete** will be called every time the model mentioned is deleted. Read about django signals [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#post-delete).

Hope this helps.

Thanks.